# Downloading large file via SFTP timeout

Tags: sftp, lftp

I've been trying to download a 3GB file from an SFTP server. However, I keep getting timeout. Downloading a smaller size file works without issue. I tried in different workstations and servers as well but no luck.

Using LFTP I got some debug information.

```
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l xxxx xx.xx.xx sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Password Authentication
<--- Password: XXXX
<--- got a packet, length=33, type=2(VERSION), id=0
---- protocol version set to 3
---- path on wire is `file.zip'
---> sending a packet, length=32, type=3(OPEN), id=1
<--- got a packet, length=10, type=102(HANDLE), id=1
---- got file handle 30 (1)
---> sending a packet, length=10, type=8(FSTAT), id=2
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=3
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=4
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=5
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=6
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=7
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=8
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=9
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=10
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=11
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=12
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=13
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=14
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=15
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=16
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=17
<--- got a packet, length=37, type=105(ATTRS), id=2
---- file info: size=3068871392, date=Sun Dec  4 20:01:00 2016
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=5(READ), id=18
**** Timeout - reconnecting
```

After timing out, it will attempt again and fail.

Is there a limit on file downloads via SFTP, if what could be the issue?